# How is a condition on symplectic triviality expressed in Chern classes?

Tags: differential-topology, characteristic-classes, morse-theory

The following is taken from *Audin, Damian: Morse Theory and Floer Homology*:

[image: Assumption 6.2.2 from the book]

My questions about this:

Question 1:

> I understand "exists a symplectic trivialization" as: There exists a symplectic vector space $F$ and an isomorphism of symplectic fiber bundles $f:\omega ^* TW \rightarrow S^2 \times F$.
>   Is that what is meant?

Question 2:

> The vector bundle (with complex structure given by a symplectic structure and some metric on $W$) $\omega ^*TW$ being trivial is equivalent to $c_k(\omega^*TW)=0$ for $k>0$.
>   Why the shorthand $\langle c_1(TW), \pi_2(W) \rangle =0$ then?
>   Why is nothing said about the other Chern classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: Yes.

Question 2: Note that $c_{i}(\omega^{*}TW) \in H^{2i}(S^{2},\mathbb{Z})$. For $i>1$ we have that $H^{2i}(S^{2},\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ (because $S^{2}$ is a $2$-dimensional manifold), hence the chern class $c_{i}$ vanishes for $i>1$. This is why there is no reference to the other Chern classes.